# "Compilation failed but no error lines" on working java program (jGRASP)

Tags: jgrasp

I'm an amateur programmer. I use jGRASP.

I made a lot of functional, running, zero-error programs and copied them to a new computer. Now, when I try to run them, I get that message: "compilation failed but no error lines."

What's going on here? I'd like any help as soon as possible, I have an assignment due.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the JDK installed (not just JRE)?

What is the compiler output? Any general messages there (not related to your code, but something like a missing javac or javac crashing)?

Is the source code in the correct package structure?

Are the source files in a directory where your login account does not have write access?